# is there a way to enable a submit button on checked

Tags: html, checkbox, checked

I'm trying to enable a submit/go-to site button when only one of my checkboxes(any single box) has been checked - can anyone help?
this is the checkbox I'm using

```
<input type="checkbox" id="number2" name="number2" value="2">
<label for="number2">02 </label>
```

hope that helps

if you could give me help using HTML and CSS as I don't know how to use scripts that would be great thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Robert! Check out this first -  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp it might help.

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="number2" name="number2" checked />
```

the `checked` attribute is for Checkbox Input element, when you use it and open your page, it have to check your checkbox automatic!

Comment: thanks for that but i was looking for a way to un hide a submit button when a checkbox is ticked but not just one there are say 5 checkboxes but it only takes one to un hide the button

Answer (score 0):

You have to use JS, sample:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="number2" name="number2" value="2" onclick="
    if (this.checked)
        document.getElementById('SomeSubmitButton').enable = true;
">
```

I told:
When user clicked on this Checkbox, enable `#SomeSubmitButton` if that's checked.